# Angular Data tables multiple row section headers

Tags: sorting, datatables, angular-directive

I have a table that is already listed in ascending desired order with two distinct sections and I want to add headers for each section but I'm not quite sure how to do so. I am using the directive Angular datatables and would like to have the end result have row titles like the "Status:New" and "Status:Open" in the example image below.

[image: I want implement row titles like the "Status:New" and "Status:Open" in image below]

Comment: It's not clear what the solution would look like. Do you have an example?

Comment: @jonmrich See the row names "Status: New" and "Status:Open"? I want to add titles like that to my data table. I am using angular-datatables. Do you see the image?

Comment: Got it...so the image is what you want, not what you have now. Correct?

Comment: Yes, the image is what I want @jonmrich

Comment: Currently there is no supported way to fix rows in the middle of your table. Your best bet is to create two tables, like @jonmrich suggests in his answer. The only other way is to manually mess with the <tr> and <td> elements, but that's complicated and risks messing up some dataTables features. Another potential option is to add a column to each row that holds its status (icon/text/whatever) and sort by those. In fact, now that I think of it, if you're willing to fix the sort order you could add a special row that "pretends" to be a divider, although that's a bit hack-y.

Comment: Yes, at ChrisH states this is not supported in any way.  Even if you insert a styled <tr> which looks like a header, you will end up breaking the logic when the user sort in columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much research, currently there is no supported way to fix rows in the middle of the specific table I'm working with.

Answer (score 0):

Add something like this after your initial code for your table. Assuming you're using 2 tables.

```
var table1 = $("#your_top_table").DataTable({});
$(table.table().header()).append('<tr><td>Status: New</td></tr>');

var table2 = $("#your_bottom_table").DataTable({});
$(table2.table().header()).append('<tr><td>Status: Open</td></tr>');
```

Comment: I am not using two tables. I am just getting back one array of data that is already sorted in a specific order. @jonmrich

Comment: Are you able to add a fixed row to the top of the table for starters? Dividing this with another fixed row at some dynamically determined position is going to be very difficult.